# How to create a clock through given time in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Lets say I have a calculated time in a certain format like this

`2 years, 1 months, 2 days, 15 hours, 6 minuts , 0 seconds` Now I want it to make it act like clock like...

`2 years, 1 months, 2 days, 15 hours, 5 minuts , 59 seconds`

...

`2 years, 1 months, 2 days, 15 hours, 5 minuts , 58 seconds`

How is it achievable?

I thought of a solution that to send ajax request to a script, that echoes  new time, every second but that wasn't appropriate idea.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a plugin such as [this one](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/).

Or you could use a `setInterval` function:

```
setInterval(function() {
  //Your code to decrease the timer
}, 1000)
```

That function will run every second, so you can update your countdown accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. See I have calculated a `$time` through a function. 
I just want to set that setInterval returned value to `span`